# No connector available using eclipse aether package to deploy through maven plugin

Tags: maven, connector, aether

I am trying to use Maven 3.1.0 and the Eclipse Aether 0.9.0.M3.  I have set it up according to their document and trying to run it as a maven plugin.  This is a link to their deploy [example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/DeployArtifacts.java).  I substituted my repository name in the list but when I run the plugin I get the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.company.maven.plugin.sample:nexus-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:deploy-repository (default-cli) on project NexusHelper: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository internal-repository (http://nexus.company.com/content/repositories/incubator/) of type default using the available factories -> [Help 1]

I can take this same code example and run it in a standalone jar and it works perfectly.  I wanted to keep everything together as one plugin if possible and not have a plugin and a standalone jar along with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this is because this connector was not auto-injected. After I did this manually, I started having "wrong method signature" errors, which lead me to a fact that Maven 3.1.0 uses Aether 0.9.0M2.

Switching to this version didn't work out for me and there are no samples, so I'm now starting using Sonatype Aether.