# wagon ssh / scp: No connector available to access repository ... of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory

Tags: maven, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon

**Is this a bug of wagon-ssh 2.10?**

**What might work?**

E.g. what combination of Maven, Wagon-SSH and pom settings will get the behaviour back that was there with Maven 3.0.5 and wagon-ssh 2.4?

After upgrading to wagon-ssh 2.10  in my pom.xml to check whether this would fix my problems according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-177
see also [How to fix or workaround wagon bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318793/how-to-fix-or-workaround-wagon-bug)

I get the following error message:

```
No connector available to access repository XXX-snapshot-repository 
(scp://XXX/srv/repo/snapshots/) of type default 
using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

Looking into [No connector available using eclipse aether package to deploy through maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009649/no-connector-available-using-eclipse-aether-package-to-deploy-through-maven-plug)

I was assuming it might be a maven version problem. Indeed I had been sticking
to an older 3.0.5 maven for a while since the [wagon-ssh had been broken](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5559) for scp transfers for many months

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
```

So i upgraded to Maven 3.3.3

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
```

which slightly modifies the error message:

```
Cannot access scp://XXX/srv/repo/snapshots/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

Looking into 
[Failed to deploy maven project, no connector available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730596/failed-to-deploy-maven-project-no-connector-available)

there seem to be different types of ConnectorFactories

1. WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory (Maven 3.0.5)
2. BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory (Maven 3.3.3)
3. AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory (Maven ?)

Looking into https://stackoverflow.com/a/18253897/1497139
there is a pointer to http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html which is supposed to explain how to add connectors (6 people upvoted this answer) - but i do not find a mention of ConnectorFactory there.

an internet search for

```
wagon-ssh ConnectorFactory scp
```

has some of the links already mentioned in this question and:

[Is there any way of having maven scp wagon work consistently on linux/mac/windows platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819775/is-there-any-way-of-having-maven-scp-wagon-work-consistently-on-linux-mac-window)

where the configuration style is mentioned that I had been using successfully for some 2 years now.

I observed that the following download happened when i did a maven install on the parent pom.xml alone:

```
mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/2.10/wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar
Downloaded: http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/2.10/wagon-provider-api-2.10.jar (53 KB at 129.4 KB/sec)
```

But this doesn't change the situation for the child project.

Here is an excerpt of the pom:

```xml
   <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>


   <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>XXX-snapshot-repository</id>
            <name>XXX Maven2 Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>scp://XXX/srv/repo/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/224 has a similar error-message but no hint on what the reason might be

Comment: and another case: http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Flex-Mavenizer-Deploying-to-server-using-SCP-td5432.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must admit I feel slightly stupid but since others might have similar issues I am showing what resolved the issue:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>XXX-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../XXX/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

so the pom declarations shown above where merely not being picked up at all.

Comment: the relativePath to the parent pom needs to resolve - if there is no pom the parent's information will  not be useable

Answer (score 5):

You have a submenu layout and

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
      <version>2.10</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Was not found while uploading! As you resolved the issue via referencing `<relativePath>` the parent, the `wagon-ssh` was finally found in the parent-pom.

By the way, if you run into this problem by `mvn release` and this is the only step that failed, you do not need to release again, just type `mvn deploy` to complete the release!

Answer (score 1):

I tried 'mvn install' in pom.xml location and all the things got configured automatically. Now I'm able to run my project as maven install.

Answer (score 0):

use `<url>scpexe://XXX/srv/repo/snapshots/</url>` unless  `<url>scp://XXX/srv/repo/snapshots/</url>`

look up [deploy-ssh-external](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html)